# Expected declaration before } token

Tags: arduino-uno

Below is my code. The idea is it is supposed to wait for the ? character, print K, and turn on the LED. If it does not detect ? then it should keep waiting.

Below is my code:

```
incomingByte = Serial.read();
sendBack = K;
int pollTime = 200;

int ledPin = 9;

bool running = true;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600); //Set data rate.
}

void loop() {
while(Serial.available())  {
  if(Serial.read == '?')  {
  Serial.print(sendBack);
  pinMode(9,OUTPUT);
  else  {
   delayMicroseconds(pollTime);
  }
}
}
}
```

Comment: why do you declare 9 as an output in the void loop???

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); //set baud rate.
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available())  { //Gets you the number of bytes that are available to be read from the serial port.
    if (Serial.read() == '?') {
      Serial.println("OK");
      digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
      delay(1000);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(9, LOW);
  }
}
```